# Convert Numeric to String using for loop

Tags: r

For example I have the code below:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c("4")
c <- c("5")
d <- c(a,b,c)
```

I want to convert all item of the list d into string. I use the for loop below:

```
for (i in d) {
i <- toString(i)
}
```

But when I check class(a) it is still numeric. Can anyone tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: Please add the desired outcome, it is not quite clear if you want a string of `1:5` or a list containing a, b and c as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, your problem is that you're overwriting your index variable `i`, which doesn't mutate the underlying objects as it might in other languages. This is why `class(a)` remains numeric.

In R all elements of a vector must be the same type. If they're not then they will be coerced in the following order: logical, integer, double, character. Additionally, when the inputs to a vector are other vectors `c()` will flatten the vector. We can see this in your code by looking at the output of `d`:

```
d
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```

Vectors `a`, `b`, and `c` have been flatted into one vector and since `b` and `c` are character vectors then `a` has been coerced to be character. To preserve their types, as @Base_R_Best_R commented you should use a list object:

```
d <- list(a = a, b = b, c = c)
```

---

You then have several ways to accomplish what you need in base `R` (this is not comprehensive):

**for loop**

```
for (i in seq_along(d)){ 
  d[[i]] <- as.character(d[[i]])
}
```

**lapply**

This would be a better option as it will be faster than the `for` loop and is a very common way of applying a function over a list object in R.

```
d <- lapply(d, as.character)
```

---

Lastly, if your intention was to have a flattened vector of five elements then you don't need a `for` loop, `as.character` is vectorized so it will work on your entire vector:

```
as.character(c(a,b,c))
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"

as.character(a)
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

But this is redundant because as previously mentioned `c()` has implicitly coerced everything to be a string.